# ¿Cómo recorrer un SELECT para obtener el VALUE de aquellos OPTIONS que NO están seleccionados? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, mvc

tengo el siguiente código en JavaScript que devuelve una lista de supervisores y a la vez muestra la cantidad de ventas en un DASHBOARD simple, esto SIEMPRE Y CUANDO se seleccione el supervisor, por DEFAULT el SELECT devuelve un  OPTION con el atributo SELECTED que indica "Seleccione una opción", acá no me devuelve nada y el DASHBOARD muestra "0" en los campos.

```javascript
function listar_supervisores() {
  var idusuario = $("#idusuario").val();
  var rol = $("#idrol").val();
  $.ajax({
    url: "../controlador/dashboard/controlador_listar_supervisores.php",
    type: 'POST'
  }).done(function (resp) {
    var data = JSON.parse(resp);
    var cadena = "<option value='0' disabled selected>Seleccione una opción</option>";
    if (data.length > 0) {
      for (var index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
        if (data[index][2] == idusuario && data[index][3] == rol) {
          cadena += "<option value='" + data[index][0] + "'>" + data[index][1] + "</option>";

        } else if (data[index][3] != rol) {
          cadena += "<option value='" + data[index][0] + "'>" + data[index][1] + "</option>";
        }

      }
      $("#cbm_supervisor").html(cadena);

    } else {
      cadena += "<option value=''>No se encontraron datos</option>";
      $("#cbm_supervisor").html(cadena);

    }
  })

  setTimeout(function () {
    var idsupervisor = $("#cbm_supervisor").val();
    listar_asesor(idsupervisor);
  }, 250);
}
```

[image: Dashboard]

El requerimiento pide que en principio, el DASHBOARD muestre el total de las ventas de todos los supervisores, es decir, que en lugar de que coloque 0 muestre la cantidad total de ventas y por cada estado ("instaladas, en ejecución, rechazadas, observadas) muestre el total de igual forma, pero por estado.

En principio, lo que pensaba era recorrer el SELECT para obtener los OPTIONS que no estén seleccionados (los supervisores) y así obtener la cantidad de las ventas totales y por estado, pero no se me ocurre como hacerlo.

Dejó también el script que permite mostrar las cantidades:

```javascript
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        //cantidad_ventas_vs();
        // cantidad_ventas_ingresadas();
        listar_supervisores();
        cantidad_ventas_instaladas_vs(); 
        cantidad_ventas_en_ejecucion_vs();
        cantidad_ventas_rechazadas_vs();
        cantidad_ventas_observadas_vs();
        cantidad_ventas_vs();
    });

    $("#cbm_supervisor").change(function() {
        var idsupervisor = $("#cbm_supervisor").val();
        listar_asesor(idsupervisor);
        cantidad_ventas_instaladas_vs(); 
        cantidad_ventas_en_ejecucion_vs();
        cantidad_ventas_rechazadas_vs();
        cantidad_ventas_observadas_vs();
        cantidad_ventas_vs();
    })
</script>
```

Desde ya, gracias a todos por las respuestas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno para obtener los option seleccionados es:

```
var options= $('#select option:selected');
```

Y para los NO seleccionados seria

```
var options= $('#select option:not(:selected)')
```

espero que eso te sea de ayuda

```js
var optionSelected= $('#cars option:selected');
console.log(optionSelected.val());
var optionUnselected= $('#cars option:not(:selected)');
$.each(optionUnselected,(index,value)=>{
console.log(value);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="cars" id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes" selected>Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: No me funciona correctamente, me sale lo siguiente:

[Imagen](https://i.imgur.com/eHYwVH9.png)

Comment: @Isanchezo edité la respuesta, agregue un ejemplo práctico